# autofac instance a class in constructor

Tags: c#, configuration, inversion-of-control, autofac

I have the next problem, i dont understand why this code dont work i think is because i dont injectate the class of constructor by autofac but i dont know how do that, can us help me to do that the better way?

Before I add the generator this work if i comment the generator code in service work.

This is my code:

I have a class Controller that invoke a serv:

```
public class ZonesController : Controller
{
    private IZoneService zoneService;

    public ZonesController(IZoneService zoneService)
    {
        this.zoneService = zoneService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    //Do work
}
```

This is the service and interface:

```
public class ZoneService : IZoneService
{
    private readonly IZoneRepository zoneRepository;
    private readonly IDtoFactory dtoFactory;
    private readonly ZoneGenerator zoneGenerator;

    public ZoneService(IZoneRepository zoneRepository, 
                              IDtoFactory dtoFactory,
                              ZoneGenerator zoneGenerator)
    {
        this.zoneRepository = zoneRepository;
        this.dtoFactory = dtoFactory;
        this.zoneGenerator = zoneGenerator;
    }

    public void Add(ZoneDetailDTO zone)
    {
         zoneGenerator.Generate(zone);
    }

    //Do Work
}

public interface IZoneService
{
    void Add(ZoneDetailDTO zone);
    //Do Methods
}
```

The generator invoke ohter class, factories:

```
public class ZoneGenerator
    {
        private readonly ZoneFactory zoneFactory;
        private readonly IZoneRepository zoneRepository;

        public ZoneGenerator(ZoneFactory zoneFactory, IZoneRepository zoneRepository)
        {
            this.zoneFactory = zoneFactory;
            this.zoneRepository = zoneRepository;
        }

        public void Generate(ZoneDetailDTO zoneModel)
        {
           var zone = zoneFactory.Create(zoneModel);
           zoneRepository.Add(zone);
        }
    }
```

The Factory:

```
public class ZoneFactory
{
    private readonly ZoneMapFactory zoneMapFactory;
    private readonly ZoneScheduleFactory zoneScheduleFactory;

    public ZoneFactory(ZoneMapFactory zoneMapFactory,
                              ZoneScheduleFactory zoneScheduleFactory)
    {
        this.zoneMapFactory = zoneMapFactory;
        this.zoneScheduleFactory = zoneScheduleFactory;
    }

    public Zone Create(zoneDetailDTO zone)
    {
        var map = zoneMapFactory.Create(zone.Map.Address, zone.Map.Latitude, zone.Map.Longitude);
        var schedule = zoneScheduleFactory.Create(zone.Schedule.StartHour, zone.Schedule.EndHour);

        return new Zone(zone.Name, 
                        zone.ProvinceId, 
                        map, 
                        schedule, 
                        zone.Tags);
    }
}
```

And finally my container:

```
//method in Startup class Asp.Net Core
public IServiceProvider ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSingleton(_ => Configuration);

        // Add framework services.
        services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry(Configuration);

        services.AddMvc();

        var containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();
        containerBuilder.RegisterModule<DefaultModule>();
        containerBuilder.Populate(services);
        var container = containerBuilder.Build();
        return new AutofacServiceProvider(container);
    }

public class DefaultModule : Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ZoneService>().As<IZoneService>();
        builder.RegisterType<ZoneRepository>().As<IZoneRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<ProvinceService>().As<IProvinceService>();
        builder.RegisterType<ProvinceRepository>().As<IProvinceRepository>();
        builder.RegisterType<DtoFactory>().As<IDtoFactory>();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have missed to add to your `Load` method the following:

```
builder.RegisterType<ZoneGenerator>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<ZoneFactory>().AsSelf();
builder.RegisterType<ZoneMapFactory>().AsSelf(); 
builder.RegisterType<ZoneScheduleFactory>().AsSelf();
```

Comment: You are right, thanks a lot!!!, Take advantage, you know some way that you can automatically inject factories, respositories and service or this is the only way. Thanks again.